# Internal "share" answer links are not converted to a title

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

```
Answer:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760326/merge-multiple-lines-two-blocks-in-vim/10760494  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10760494/298479  
Question:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760326/merge-multiple-lines-two-blocks-in-vim  
https://stackoverflow.com/q/10760326/298479
```

ends up as

> Answer:
>   [Merge multiple lines (two blocks) in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760326/merge-multiple-lines-two-blocks-in-vim/10760494)
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/10760494/298479
>   Question:
>   [Merge multiple lines (two blocks) in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760326/merge-multiple-lines-two-blocks-in-vim)
>   [Merge multiple lines (two blocks) in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10760326/298479)

As you can see, the share-answer link is not converted to the question title. This is kind of annoying, especially when linking an answer in another answer - the fastest way to get the answer link is the "share" button. Having to open the URL to get the long URL is annoying (additionally chances for one of the share badges are lowered).